# Why do we need to hold a file object inside a variable?

Tags: python-3.x

```
url = 'learn.txt'

variable1 = open(url, 'w')

writethis = variable1.write('Oh hey!')

writethis

variable1.close
```

Okay, so if that works then why doesn't this:

```
url = 'learn.txt'

open(url, 'w').write('Oh hey!')

open(url, 'w').close
```

I am using Python version 3.4.2

There is no error, but the text file is empty..

I tried this shortcut because it appears to be the same thing, except without assigning a variable to the function.  I considered just accepting the fact that everything has to be done a certain way, but my curiosity is overpowering.

Comment: There is no error, but the text file is empty..

Comment: You gotta also call `.close()` or at the very least `.flush()`

Comment: @Pythong edit the question to include this information.

Comment: Okay, I closed it and the text file is still blank.

Comment: @Pythong what does `import sys; print(sys.version)` show you?

Comment: 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you have problems with the second example is that

```
x = open(url, "w")
y = open(url, "w")
x is y
```

yields false. This means that the two opens return file-like objects that have nothing to do with each other. When you

```
open(url, 'w').write('Oh hey!')
```

that's actually fine and on *normal* exit the opened file will be flushed and closed. Following that with

```
open(url, 'w').close()
```

firstly cannot close the file object from the first example line, and secondly opening an existing file in 'w' mode will first truncate it to zero length. That snippet will fall of the end, flush and close each file object but the underlying file (url) has already been truncated to zero length.

Your first example is correct and is more common than the second; the second, as you note, is fatally flawed. More idiomatic and safer is:

```
with open(url, 'w') as out_file:
    outfile.write('Oh hey!\n')
    # other stuff you might want to write to out_file
```

The context manager (with) ensures that out_file gets flushed and closed even if there is an exception raised in its body.

---

This answer is based on the assumption that your calls to close are typos and really should be `.close()` with the parentheses.